# error with passing char to a type char*, while reading in stdin

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

In a part of a larger program, I'm trying to read in a line into an element of a struct into array of structs. I want to skip the spaces in the line, and the line looks something like this: 'vt ab cda'

this is the error I'm getting:
error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'char *'; take the address with & [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
strcpy(dictionary[counter].line_two[i],c);

here's the part of my code:

```
for (counter=0; counter<=MAX_DICT_WORDS-1; counter++)
   {    
        
        if (counter%3==1)
            
        {
            i=0;
            char c;
            c=getchar();
            while (!(c==' '))
            {
                strcpy(dictionary[counter].line_two[i],c);
                i+=1;
            }
        }
```

dictionary is my array of structs,
the struct has 3 elements, line_one, line_two and line_three
Please let me know how I can fix the error!

Comment: `c` is a character; `strcpy()` is for copying strings — pointers to null-terminated arrays of characters.  A single character is not a string.  Unless it contains `'\0'`, taking the address of `c` and passing it to `strcpy()` would be a bad idea (and if it does contain `'\0'`, there's no point in calling `strcpy()`.  Note that `while (!(c==' '))` is odd; `while (c != ' ')` would be more conventional.  However, the loop is wrong because `c` doesn't change; it gets executed no times or forever and no in between.  Also, `dictionary[counter].line_two[i]` is a character, not a pointer.

Comment: strcpy takes strings as arguments, but c is not a string. you don't show how your dictionary is declared so it is difficult to help further. in general though either read letter by letter into a temp buffer and then when you find a whitespace strcpy that word into your dictionary or read line by line. now i seems to be incremented per letter.

Comment: strcpy is mad at you for giving it a bad data type; c is a `char` and needs to be a `char *`. Maybe declare it like `char c[1]`?

Comment: Use `dictionary[counter].line_two[i++] = c;` instead of `strcpy()`.  But you also need to fix the while loop — probably into an `if`: `if (c != ' ')`, I think.  You'll need to null terminate the string too.

Comment: @NickReed: It must be at least `char c[2];` so you can have a null terminator.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to fix that, but now I'm getting a segfault error, how would you recommend reading in a line with spaces?

Comment: Use standard C [`fgets()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or POSIX [`getline()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html).

Comment: "passing 'char' to parameter of type 'char *'" is a very self-explanatory compiler error.